# how to detect when winform usercontrol DesktopLocation has changed

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls, location, desktop

As per the title, how can a usercontrol detect when it's position on the desktop has changed?

E.g detect when the window has been dragged across the desktop, OR some higher level container has moved within the top level window eg a sliding panel type of control

Similar to how LocationChanged event works but this only works if the user control has moved within it's container as far as I can tell.

And ideally something that works if the control is hosted in WPF via windowsformhost

Comment: A control is not intended to know about the movements of its parent. It should never be relevant. All controls do have a `Move` event that you can handle, which is raised when that control is moved. What exactly are you trying to create?

Comment: The user control is to be a kind of proxy for another user control in a sepearte exe that places the actual user control at the proxies position on the screen i.e. overlays the proxy user control. Move event does not get fired in the above scenarios

Comment: I didn't say it did. You have to read the *entire* comment, not just the part with code formatting. What you've asked for doesn't make any sense: child controls have no knowledge of the movements of their parents, and that's by design.

Comment: In response to your edit, that sounds like bad design to me. Is there any reason that you can't use the typical .NET design patterns for this? Is the control that you're hosting, the one that's located in a separate EXE, written in another language? Do you not have any control over that source code?

Comment: for back ground its a follow on for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488813/display-a-windowless-forms-picturebox-always-on-top. If you knwo of a design pattern that accomplishes it happy to hear it

Comment: Yeah, that question explains where you made your first error, unfortunately it doesn't explain the problem being solved. Someone suggested a poor workaround, and now you're running into other limitations of that hack. The parent-child relationship is an important one in Windows. You need to set the parent of the "hosted" control to its actual parent, rather than treating it as a random, free-floating control on the desktop. I can't see how this would ever work--what happens if the user closes the app that hosts the "extra" pop-up window? Suddenly your app breaks and they can't figure out why.

Comment: what happens if ... obvisoulsy there are complexities to be handled. Neverthless, it's a real world requirement that the client wants implemented, not a philosophical debate on the flexibility of .net.

Comment: Requirements aren't very "real world" when what they require is not possible. It should be clear by now that my advice is to investigate alternative approaches. I've also suggested looking into setting the parent of the control. This is typically accomplished using the nominal function, but you may also need to change some window styles for the control. There is no such event raised in WinForms as that which you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above your approach should be avoided ... i can just suggest to go for something else...

however the framework allows you to register on a move event ...

this event exists for your control, representing movement of your control within its parent container...
it also exists for the parent control, representing the movement of that parent control in the "grandparent" container...
etc...

since a control knows its parent, you could probably walk that chain of controls until you get to the toplevel control, and register for every controls move event along that chain ... that way you should get notified when the screen pos changes ...

have i mentioned that you SHOULD not do this ? ... well, you have been warned ...

Comment: Yes, this is the approach my later comments were driving towards. The key to making this work is ensuring that the control in question is actually set as a child of the parent. You can't walk the chain for a merely logical or positional relationship, you actually have to let Windows know what your plans are.